# why won't this code cause infinite loop?

Tags: ios, xcode, properties, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Xcode template code : MasterDetailApplication (use core data) 
in MasterViewController.m , the implementation of

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
  if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return __fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController  = aFetchedResultsController;
NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
     // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
     // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return __fetchedResultsController;
}
```

the question is : this code uses property inside a getter , why won't this cause a infinite loop ? 
i mean this line :

```
self.fetchedResultsController  = aFetchedResultsController;
```

Answer (score 3):

the code uses the property inside the getter, but with the `self.prop = value` syntax, which will call the **setter**, (and not the getter inside the getter). So there is no reason this code generate an infinite loop.

Anyway, this is quite a strange implementation of the getter.

Normally there will be no problem calling the setter method inside the getter method if the setter does not call itself the getter. Of course if the setter itself calls the getter, there you will have your infinite loop, getter calling setter calling getter and so on.

Comment: +1 however you cannot guarantee that there will be no problem calling the equivalent setter from the getter; doing so certainly smacks of lack of clarity of thought...

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using the setter, not the getter.

```
 self.property = something;
```

This will call the setter:

```
 [self setProperty:something];
```

and not the getter:

```
 [self property];
```